# Android build not able to fetch the all the "VERSION_CODES" available

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

Currently i am working on an android, i am using eclipse tool. As i wanted to get list of all the android version_Codes available for the project. but currently my tool/eclipse only shows version_codes till Froyo. I have added the minimum android sdk value to 8 and target sdk value is 17 I have  Below is my Androidmanifest.xml and project code i am trying to implement the code

```
   Java file
int FROYO = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO;
int JELLYBEAN = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN;

 Part of Androidmanifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.Android.Afaria" android:versionCode="50" android:sharedUserId="com.afaria.client" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="6.60.6172">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Here in java file eclipse autosuggest is not suggesting any version code above FROYO.[image]

Comment: did you get the answer of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project. go to Properties > android > and select Jelly bean as your target build.

Wait a few seconds or do a Project> clean and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change your project build target and keep your minimum SDK as the target, you can set the build versions as a constant in your class and test against that. Get "constant value" of the SDK you would like to test against from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#GINGERBREAD_MR1

Then declare a constant in your class:

```
public static final int HONEYCOMB = 11;
```

Then you can check against this constant in your code like so:

```
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < HONEYCOMB) {
             ...your code
         }
```

Note: I have tested this in the device emulator and seems to be working fine, will update my answer if any problems occur on actual devices.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug, could be some limitation. If you want to see the full list you can see them [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

Comment: its not a bug, try yourself